# An unbiased dice is thrown n times what is the probability that the product of numbers would be even?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I am doing it like $n\choose1 $ $ \frac{1}{2} {\frac{1}{2}}^{n-1}$ + $n\choose 2 $${\frac{1}{2}}^2 {\frac{1}{2}}^{n-2} + ......+$$n\choose n $ ${\frac{1}{2}}^n $
Is this correct?
Further I am not able to simplify it significantly beyond
${\frac{1}{2}}^n \frac{n!}{(n-1)!}(1+\frac{n-1}{2!}+......+\frac{(n-1)!}{n!})$ how to simplify it further?

Comment: All numbers or any numbers?

Comment: product of numbers is even I edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are asking what is the probability that at least one outcome is even.

You need to calculate $1$ minus the probability of the complementary event:

- The probability that all outcomes are odd is $\left(\frac12\right)^n$
- The probability that not all outcomes are odd is $1-\left(\frac12\right)^n$

Your way is binomial distribution with $p=\frac12$:

$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\cdot\left(\frac12\right)^{k}\cdot\left(1-\frac12\right)^{n-k}=$

$1-\sum\limits_{k=0}^{0}\binom{n}{k}\cdot\left(\frac12\right)^{k}\cdot\left(1-\frac12\right)^{n-k}=$

$1-\binom{n}{0}\cdot\left(\frac12\right)^{0}\cdot\left(1-\frac12\right)^{n-0}=$

$1-\left(\frac12\right)^n$

Which is indeed the same.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention that product of numbers are even not numbers, edited the question.

Comment: @Ankit: OK, see updated answer.

Comment: The way that I have done it does that make any sense? I get your point but just wanted to check if my approach is correct or not.

Comment: @Ankit: See updated answer.